# object not callable python when parsing a json response

Tags: python

I have a response from a URL which is of this format.

```
'history': {'all': [[u'09 Aug', 1,5'],[u'16 Aug', 2, 6]]}
```

And code is :

```
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data["fixture_history"]['all']
customObject = MyObject (
                           history = data["history"]['all']
                        )
```

Printing works but in my custom class I am seeing this error :

```
    history = data["history"]['all']
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My class is :

```
class MyObject:
    #init
    def _init_(self,history):
        self.hstory = history
```

Comment: it should be `__init__` not `_init_`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Printing works but in my custom class I am seeing this error :
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I bet your your class is defined in a module named `MyObject.py` and that you imported it as `import MyObject` instead of `from MyObject import MyObject`, so in your calling code, name `MyObject` is bound to the module, not the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you Class is defined in a different Module please make sure that that you have imported it the right way ie. you need to use from X import Y format but not Import X and expect it to work as if we do it that way we need to let python know the module we are calling it from.

And i am not very sure but i think the typo in the constructor might case the issue as stated 
bigOTHER